# while loop to compare files with each other

Tags: linux, while-loop

I achived result from for loop as below. Only thing to avoid is to compare same files.

```
   $ for (( i = 0; i <= 9; i++ ))      ### Outer for loop ###
> do
>
>     for (( j = 0 ; j <= 9; j++ )) ### Inner for loop ###
>     do
>           echo "awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC"$j"_Log" SPM_CC"$i"_Log" > SPM_CC"$j"_DWN"""
>     done
>
>
> done
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
```

I need to fetch various linux command out of loop where Files need to compare with each others. In order to get same need to contruct double while loop.

For example: SPM_CC1_Log with SPM_CC0_Log to SPM_CC9_Log and vice versa.

Here is my while loop

```
    n=9
i=0
while [ $i -le $n ]
do
  j=1
  while [ $j -le $n ]
  do
    echo "awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC"$j"_Log" SPM_CC"$i"_Log" > SPM_CC"$j"_DWN"""
   i=$((i+1))
   j=$((j+1))
  done
done
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
```

Whereas I need below output from while loop to compare each files with each other.

```
    awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN

awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN

----
----
----
----

awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
```

Answer (score 0):

Dears,

The below code solved my purpose.

```
    $ for (( i = 0; i <= 9; i++ ))      ### Outer for loop ###
> do
>
>     for (( j = 0 ; j <= 9; j++ )) ### Inner for loop ###'
>     do
>            if [[ $i -eq $j ]]; then
>             continue
>               fi
>           echo "awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC"$j"_Log" SPM_CC"$i"_Log" > SPM_CC"$j"_DWN"""
>     done
> done
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC0_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC1_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC2_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC3_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC4_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC5_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC6_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC7_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC9_Log SPM_CC8_Log > SPM_CC9_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC0_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC0_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC1_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC1_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC2_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC2_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC3_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC3_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC4_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC4_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC5_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC5_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC6_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC6_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC7_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC7_DWN
awk -f cmp.awk SPM_CC8_Log SPM_CC9_Log > SPM_CC8_DWN
```